# Creating a random number of class objects in python

Tags: python, class, loops, object

Is there a correct way to loop through a for loop and create a number of objects, but not know how many time it loops? From what i've researched I can loop through a list of predetermined strings and create objects from those, but what if I don't have a predetermined number to loop through.

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x
        self.y
        self.z

for x in range(random_number):
    x = Item(1,2,3)
```

How would I go about this, and know the difference between the first and last object created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you going to do with these objects? If you just want to create a random amount with a for loop, do what you are doing. However, it looks to me like you want to put them in a [list](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
mylist = []
for i in range(random_number):
    mylist.append(Item(1,2,3))
```

Alternatively, you could use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
mylist = [Item(1,2,3) for i in range(random_number)]
```

Comment: I'm using the objects in a game where the objects represent people. After a condition is met there will be more of these objects implemented into the game, so there could be 100+ objects created.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the objects in a list. Then you can reference the first and last items using indexing.

```
items = [Item(1,2,3) for x in range(random_number)]
first = items[0]
last = items[-1]
```

Comment: `first, *rest, last = items` -- if on Python 3 IMO the unpacking is nicer than the index-based getting.

Answer (score 0):

you could use an array to keep track of objects created

```
object_list = []
for x in range(random_number):
    object_list.append(Item(1, 2, 3))
```

the first object created would be `object_list[0]` and the last would be `object_list[-1]`